# Is there any 'out-of-the-box' 2D/3D plotting library for C++?

Tags: c++, graph, wxwidgets, plot

I looked at the different options for plotting functions (or other types of graphs) in an interactive window. I mostly use wxWidgets but I'd be open to any other "interfaces".

### **Looking at what is available, here is what I've found**:

**wxPlot**: Not updated since 2006. But it would be a good candidate if it was...

**wxMathPlot**: Very new, not mature, few features (still active?)

**libgraph**: Outdated, not rebust, 2D only and outputs images only.

**koolplot**: Too basic, no control over the created window.

**EasyBMP**: Very basic, only images output.

**plotutils**: Command line only.

**plplot**: C and C++ API are barely maintained. It is in fact on this that wxPlot is based. Could be a could candidate also if C and C++ interface we're updated.

Any comments? Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Even though this thread is old but gold. [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/) is very recommendable as well to complement this list.

Answer (score 15):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net) have many plot types, C/Fortran interface and basic data analysis

Answer (score 10):

I'm all about [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) for these needs. Pretty heavy if you don't need all the analysis support, though.

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but thank you for pointing out ROOT. I hadn't heard about it and it will be very useful!

Comment: I really hate to see good libraries released under GNU, this literally makes it useless.

Comment: @metablaster I know and have used ROOT and TMVA extensively in my time and they are very convenient given you use nix-based system. Ever since I moved on to windows, I can barely build it, let alone compile any of my own codes. It doesn't really matter because I don't work with CERN but every so often I just miss the convenience.

Answer (score 9):

You have [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) which is mature. There is a 3D version lurking somewhere. However, I have never been satisfied with the aesthetic result.

It may be worth waiting for [Qt3D](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/11/18/qt3d-brings-qt-style-coding-to-3d/) to come out to write something better yourself easily.

Answer (score 6):

I programmatically provide required input files to [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) executable and invoke it using `system()` function. It is suitable to my situation since I only want to visualize my data during research. But if you want the plotting functionality integrated into your executable file, maybe this is not for you :)

Comment: Have a look at Gnuplot iostream: a single header library giving intuitive access to the Gnuplot functionalities directly from your C++ code. I love it!

Answer (score 4):

u can use  [DISLIN](http://www.dislin.de/)

it is quite neat!

Comment: They require payment for library.

Answer (score 3):

Might [wxChart](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/wxchart/) be an option? I have not used it myself however and it looks like it hasnt been updated for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea: Use Python as embeddable scripting language to plot your graphs. Python has a plethora of [plotting libraries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting).

Comment: If you don't mind embedding a Python interpreter you get a whole lot of other benefits from having a scripting lanaguage in your application, plus access to the sort of libraries you've linked to.  +1

Comment: if compared to *writing data to files and using system call to run py scripts*, which is more convenient and faster?

Comment: @zhangxaochen it depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the game library Allegro easy to use back in the day.  Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

We use an ancient version of [ComponentOne Chart](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-chart-activex-dll/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

AntiGrain Geometry (AGG).  http://www.antigrain.com/. Its an opensource 2D vector graphics library. Its a standalone library with no additional dependencies. Has good documentation. Python plotting library matplotlib uses AGG as one of backends.

Comment: AGG is a rendering engine, not a plotting library.  Using it for plotting would require re-implementing matplotlib on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [wxArt2d](http://wxart2d.org) it is a complete framework for 2d editing and plotting. See the [screenshots](http://wxart2d.org/moin/WxArt2dScreenShots) for more examples.

Some interesting features:

- Reading and writing SVG and CVG
- Several views of the same document
- Changes are updated when idle
- Optimized drawing of 2d objects

Answer (score 1):

Hey! I'm the developer of [wxMathPlot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net)! The project is active: I just took a long time to get a new release, because the code needed a partial rewriting to introduce new features. Take a look to the new 0.1.0 release: it is a great improvement from old versions. Anyway, it doesn't provide 3D (even if I always thinking about it...).

Comment: is it able to plot in "real time"? (or near real time)? To be clear - I want to be able to update from a data source and draw as new points arrive.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL. It WILL be hard and possibly rewriting the wheel, though.
Keep in mind that OpenGL is a general 3D library, and not a specific plot library, but you can implement plotting based on it.

Comment: Downvoted because I dont think recommending to roll your own on a library recommendation question is not actually answering it.

Comment: Upvoted because once you try to get gnuplot to do what you want, you appreciate the "roll your own" approach much more. The syntax of gnuplot is incomprehensible and the programming model behind the lines of runes is not explained anywhere. In the time it takes to figure out how to see my 3d points on the screen, I would have done it with opengl and sdl two times over.