# Plotting framework

Tags: c++, qt, frameworks, plot

I'm in no way an expert on programming, not even close, and I'm event worse at GUI programming. But for a project I need to do some simple point datasets and line plots. And I need to be able to do dynamic updates.

Does anyone know any good frameworks for doing this, I would like either a Cocoa or perhaps a Qt C/C++ framework.

The other option would be to make a Qt widget myself, there are properbly lots of good tutorials out there on that, does anyone know any?

My data is going to be (x,y) with a sliding window over the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of suggestions here [Is there any 'out-of-the-box' 2D/3D plotting library for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296199/is-there-any-out-of-the-box-2d-3d-plotting-library-for-c)

Comment: Thats what I was looking for... I think, I will have a look :-)

Answer (score 3):

[qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) is what you need if you want to use Qt.

It's really poorly documented but there's a tutorial [here](http://www.thewireframecommunity.com/node/41)

Comment: Yep, but since its for a customer I would like some more eye candy, do you know any frameworks that do that? Or if qwt does it, would you post some links to examples?

Answer (score 3):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) is GPL plotting library which have both: QMathGL for Qt widget with plot, and mglGraphQT (or mglGraphFLTK, or mglGraphGLUT) for external window with plot. See these [samples](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_10.html#Using-FLTK_002fGLUT-window) for more details.