# I want to draw a graph in my winapi C program, is there any control?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, controls

Does the system come with a standard control that can be used for drawing a diagram like this?

If not, how would I go about creating a custom control to do so?

[image]

Comment: I want something like this too, in pure win32 api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely should search for any kind of such library at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) in the "[Desktop Development -> Miscellaneous"](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/miscctrl/) section. But as to me, I'd use "[A 2D data visualisation class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/425/A-2D-data-visualisation-class)" which provides a very nice set of features (from the article):

> - Normal and scatter graph modes
> - Autoscale
> - Zooming
> - Fit width, height and page
> - Mouse coordinates tracing
> - Ability to add and display interactively up to 15000 points per second (depends on the speed of the computer)
> - Panning support - just press and hold shift key while moving mouse with left button pressed
>     Graph could be drawn on any device context, including printer's one

Another option is to use *ready-to-go* **MFC** or **ActiveX** components. Very good example of first one is "[Plot Graphic Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1546/Plot-Graphic-Library)" and an example for the second one is "[GDI+ Plot ActiveX Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38272/GDI-Plot-ActiveX-Control)". As you already mentioned, all this libraries based on GDI Windows facility. BTW, you can draw this simple graph by yourself, because GDI (and GDI+) facility in Windows is very powerful.

Also, see "[SoftIntegration Graphical Library (SIGL)](http://www.softintegration.com/products/silib/graphlib/)". The library contains a lot of different plots and surfaces.

But, again, it's only about GDI. **Another variant** is to use DirectX or OpenGL. For the latter you should definitely try **[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)** (Simple DirectMedia Layer) which:

> is a cross-platform multimedia library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, 3D hardware via OpenGL, and 2D video framebuffer. 
>   As you can see it's a crossplatform library.

Good SO questions to get familiar with are:

- "[Plotting graphs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996743/plotting-graphs-in-c)"
- "[Graph drawing C++ library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library)"
- "[Is there any 'out-of-the-box' 2D/3D plotting library for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296199/is-there-any-out-of-the-box-2d-3d-plotting-library-for-c)"

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention "[ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/)" - it is the most powerful graph library, I've ever seen. Actually, it's not a library, it's "A Data Analysis Framework". The library's creators is a guys from CERN. With this library you can build almost all kind of plots and surfaces and graphics you've ever imagined. It's crossplatform and written in C++. ROOT has both: console version (where you can write command in C++, - ROOT has own C++ compiler) and a huge set of libraries to link with your projects. You can build MFC applications with its help both in MSVS 2008 and MSVS 2010.

Comment: Very frustrating.   This NOT an answer to the question that was asked,  draw a graph in a WINAPI C program.  NOT, .net, not C#, etc.

Comment: What's frustrating is your useless comment, IMHO. The answer is detailed and gives some links to existing libraries. Why don't you write your own and valid answer? Right in C++ Win32 API?

Comment: Okay, done.   See the answer referencing J Bremner's windex.   i am using it now, and it is actually pretty.  Pure simple C++, and you can use it with or without the MS IDE.

Comment: "pretty" should read that windex is actually "pretty good"

Answer (score 8):

You will find third party chart control for the Windows APIs -
http://www.gigasoft.com/graphinglibrary.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14330/Custom-Control-Graph-and-Process-Bar

Or you can draw the line graph yourself using the GDI functions *LineTo* and *MoveTo*.