# How to Embed MathGL Plots & Graphics in a win32 Application Window

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mathgl

I'd like to create and embed some simple plots into a GUI I've created in a Visual C++ win32 application. I could do something as simple as drawing rectangles and lines when handling a WM_PAINT message, but it'd probably be better in the long run if I could just import a more comprehensive package to allow me to do plotting.

"mathGL" seems like an attactive solution (although I'm open to others), but like most libraries, discussions (e.g. [Is there any 'out-of-the-box' 2D/3D plotting library for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296199/is-there-any-out-of-the-box-2d-3d-plotting-library-for-c)) and examples create extra windows, and I'd like to embed this in an existing window. Is this possible? Any ideas or suggestions for where to look?

Another option would seem to be to save an image and load the image into a win32 application, but this would seem to be more inefficient, especially if I want to update the plots & graphics frequently.

Comment: Have you encountered any specific problems you want resolved? If so, you should rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: My problem is that I want to embed some simple plots in a win32 application, and that I don't know how to do that. Not appropriate?

Comment: its depends how the 'plots' your referring to are being drawn to begin with...

Comment: I want to create the plots dynamically inside the program. I've updated my question with this detail.

Comment: Perhaps you could create an OpenGL context, and let MathGL render to it?