# Real time interactive plotting in C++

Tags: c++, plot, real-time

For my current project I want to be able to plot a `N x N` matrix in real time in C++. Where `N` is in the range between 100 and 1000. The content of the matrix changes over time. I also want to be able to interact with the matrix i.e. draw objects inside the matrix using my mouse.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296199/is-there-any-out-of-the-box-2d-3d-plotting-library-for-c) but I find it hard to decide which tool I should use.

Any reccomendations?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but Is this not what C++ is *not* invented for? -- For some time I am toying with the idea od using Flot -- https://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ -- that is java script graph library with computationaly intensive parts  writen in C++ runnig isnide WASM  ...

Comment: Working with mouse and graphics are not a part of the C++ standart. You'll have to use to use platform dependant features to make it work in C++ or use libaries that implement it. Languages like Java and C# are more suitable for the task.

Comment: @ALX23z Can you say which libaries I can use to do that?

Comment: @Samuel that depends a lot on what you actually want/need. You'd better make a research on this topic. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs for reference of several open source libraries. Graphics - both 2d and 3d are included. In the worst case scenario you can use a native interface of the platform you develop for. Usually they aren't too complicated for simple tasks - just have horrendous syntax.